# Have an Android app react to deep link

Tags: android, deep-linking

I'm trying to make my android app react to a specific deep link format. I want the app to be able to handle links in the following format:

```
href="android-app://website.org/http/a_path"
```

I have the following in my manifest file:

```
    <intent-filter android:label="App" >
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <data
            android:host="website.org"
            android:scheme="http" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    </intent-filter>
```

When I test it from the console, the app reacts to the following deeplink:

```
adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.VIEW -d "http://website.org/http/a_path" website.org
```

But it does not react to the format that I need, which is:

```
adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.VIEW -d "android-app://website.org/http/a_path" website.org
```

In this second case, I get the following error:

`Activity not started, unable to resolve Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=http://org.website/http/a_path flg=0x10000000 pkg=website.org }`

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Did you tried to change the `android:scheme="android-app"` ?

Comment: Check this article [Deep Linking with React Native](http://ihor.burlachenko.com/deep-linking-with-react-native/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to correctly set your scheme.

```
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"></action>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"></category>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"></category>
                <data android:scheme="android-app"></data>
            </intent-filter>
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not see you having filter for `android-app` scheme:

```
  <intent-filter>
      <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"></action>
      <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"></category>
      <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"></category>
      <data
           android:host="website.org"
           android:scheme="android-app" />
  </intent-filter>
```

But anyway, do not use custom schemes. See this discussion involving android framework developer: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/-hkq8-S5-Gs